# JSOM to alert users about not classified files

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom, alert, notifications

Due to the fact that I'm not able to use any powerapps, I'm limited to use javascript to achieve this goal.

I want to send and alert or email to the user, letting them know that these files have been uploaded without being filled with metadata.

Why do this?
A lot of the users tend to use the explorer to upload files inside the Document Library. By doing so a lot of file end up not being classified.

I use SharePoint online

Can someone please help with this ? Really stuck on this one.

Answer (score 1):

As you said users are uploading file via explorer you don't have control over running any javascript code also. Below are couple of options I can think of

Use MS Flow - Trigger point would be when file is created, check if metadata is empty, if so send email to user.

Other thing you can do is create a schedule flow to do same thing by getting library items which does not have metadata and send email to user.

If MSflow is not option - Create a windows console application and schedule it to run after particular period of time(daily or one/twice in day),  Use CSOM to query library items which does not have metaata and send email to user. - This won't be instant notification but should serve your purpose.

Comment: MSFlow is not an option. The notification/email would habe been been sent once a week. JavaScript would have been an option but to be honest I dont know where to start due to the fact that I dont have expereince with javascript. thank you

Comment: Javascript is something which works on browser context..if you have send it weekly you need to create batch job(console application) which will schedule to run every week. It can using C# CSOM to connect to SharePoint and using SMTP to send mails.

Comment: Do you know which first steps I would take to tackle this problem regarding the code . Would this be possible using python?

Comment: yes... via rest api....SharePoint REST API can be called from any technology... https://www.mydatahack.com/how-to-get-data-from-sharepoint-with-python/ & https://pypi.org/project/sharepoint/